# How Can I check whether DataReader has Data or not?

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

Again I have problem with checking whether DataReader object has data or not?

```
Dim cmd as SqlCommand
Dim drd as SqlDataReader

      cmd = New SqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM Stock", conx)
      drd = cmd.ExecuteReader()

      ''HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHECK WHETHER drd has Data or not

     While (drd.Read())
     {
          txtName.Text = drd.Item("StockName")
     }
```

How can I check that? Please Help me! Thank in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(drd.HasRows)
{
   //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with drd.read()

Like:

```
If drd.read() Then
    ...do things with data...
Else
    ...show message box... or just skip.
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I needed this badly!!! You rock my friend. Have an awesome weekend. Wayne

Answer (score 0):

drd.Read() will return False when there is no data. You don't have to change your code.